# In flutter, is there a way to programmatically set the initialValue in CountryPickerDropdown?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set the initialValue in countrypickerdropdown programmatically, but unable to do so, with initValue ('us') being set instead of my programmatic value. The snippet is as follow

```
child: CountryPickerDropdown(
                          initialValue: countryCode?? 'us',
                          itemBuilder: _buildDropdownItem,
                          onValuePicked: (Country country) {
                            setState(() {
                              countryName = country.name;
                              print("${country.name}");
                              intlPhoneCode = country.phoneCode;
                              print("${intlPhoneCode}");
                              countryCode = country.isoCode;
                              phoneIsVerified = false;
                            });
                          }
```

The countryCode value was gotten from an api call as follow:

```
Future<void> getProfile(String id) async {

    try{
      profile = await apiService.getProfile(id);

      countryCode = profile['countryCode'];
    }catch(ex){ 
         ...
    }
}
```

I couldn't even do it in initState.

Comment: try `setState(() {   countryCode = profile['countryCode'];  });`

Comment: This didn't work. When are pierced at their source code, the initialValue was used inside their initState, maybe that might lead to a solution.

Comment: Try to print `Country` in your logs `onValuePicked` in JSON format and then create a `Country` object and pass default values that you printed of desired `Country` in initState. Then set that object as `initialValue`. This will solve your problem.